# Unable to unwrap Promise<[CLPlacemark]>

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, cllocation, promisekit

I have a method that attempts to update my authorized status.

Using PromiseKit 6, Swift 4.2, I can't seem to get my Promise<[CLPlacemark]> to just be a CLPlacemark.

This causes a chain of errors of

```
Value of type 'Promise<[CLPlacemark]>' has no member 'foo'
```

Here's a look at my code:

```
func updateAuthStatus(status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        titleLabel.isHidden = true
        bigIconView.isHidden = true
        descriptionLabel.isHidden = true
        grantBtn.isHidden = true
        titleLabel1.isHidden = false
        loaderView.isHidden = false
        loaderView.resumeSpinning()
        CLLocationManager.requestLocation().compactMapValues { location in
            return self.coder.reverseGeocode(location: location)
        }.compactMapValues { placemark -> Void in
            if placemark.ISOcountryCode == "CA" {
                self.seal.fulfill(())
            } else if placemark.ISOcountryCode == "US" {
                if self.allowedStates.contains(placemark.administrativeArea ?? "") {
                    self.seal.fulfill(())
                } else {
                        self.seal.reject(LocationError.InvalidState(placemark.administrativeArea ?? ""))
                }
            } else {
        self.seal.reject(LocationError.InvalidCountry(placemark.ISOcountryCode ?? ""))
            }
        }
    }
    else if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
        if denied == false {
            self.seal.reject(LocationError.Unknown)
        }
        denied = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, this `promise` is returning an array of `CLPlacemark` objects so you need to get the specific `placemark` from the `array` and then use it. Here is the sample by accessing the `first` `placemark` in the `array`.

```
.compactMapValues { placemarks -> Void in
            guard let placemark = placemarks.first else { return }

            if placemark.ISOcountryCode == "CA" {
                self.seal.fulfill(())
            } else if placemark.ISOcountryCode == "US" {
                if self.allowedStates.contains(placemark.administrativeArea ?? "") {
                    self.seal.fulfill(())
                } else {
                  self.seal.reject(LocationError.InvalidState(placemark.administrativeArea ?? ""))
                }
            } else {
        self.seal.reject(LocationError.InvalidCountry(placemark.ISOcountryCode ?? ""))
            }
        }
```

**Edit**

To handle US and CA, related placemark for that country can be extracted as below,

```
.compactMapValues { placemarks -> Void in
       if let ca = placemarks.filter{ $0.ISOcountryCode == "CA"}.first {
            self.seal.fulfill(())
       } else if let usa = placemarks.filter{ $0.ISOcountryCode == "US"}.first {
            if self.allowedStates.contains(usa.administrativeArea ?? "") {
                self.seal.fulfill(())
            } else {
                let error = LocationError.InvalidState(usa.administrativeArea ?? "")
                self.seal.reject(error)
            }
    } else {
         let error = LocationError.InvalidCountry(placemarks.first?.ISOcountryCode ?? "")
         self.seal.reject(error)
     }
 }
```

Comment: I got the warning silenced by using guard let placemark = placemarks.value?first else { return } do you think that'll be fine?

Comment: @KonradWright Actually i am not sure how many elements are there in that `array` and i don't know the condition that returns more than one elements in the array. Still i can suggest you a better solution by seeing the code in this block. I believe you are only interested in `CA` and `US` so i will update the answer to handle those cases.

Comment: @KonradWright I updated the answer with a better fix.